# Typescript types - add property to process object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, webpack

I want to add a property to the `process` object in React, so `Webpack` will replace it with the `DefinePlugin` plugin:

```
declare global {
  interface Process {
    gitInfo: {
      GIT_COMMIT_DATE?: string;
      GIT_COMMIT_HASH?: string;
      GIT_BRANCH?: string;
      GIT_COMMIT_MESSAGE?: string;
    };
  }
}

const gitInfo = process.gitInfo; // Error: Property 'gitInfo' does not exist on type 'Process'.ts(2339)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `interface Process extends NodeJS.Process` and  `(process as Process).gitInfo`

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/c14133503acfab1048957ddb5c7914f983ee84de/typings/globals.d.ts#L57C2-L57C2

Comment: @bob - Not working. Same error.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - I can't use `namespace`. I need an alternative

Comment: Why not? It's just a type definition that will be erased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you are augmenting is qualified by the global `NodeJS` namespace. Therefore you need to write it as

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Process {
      gitInfo: {
        GIT_COMMIT_DATE?: string;
        GIT_COMMIT_HASH?: string;
        GIT_BRANCH?: string;
        GIT_COMMIT_MESSAGE?: string;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***Remarks***

After some discussion in comments, it became clear that the OP was attempting to avoid namespaces due to an eslint TypeScript rule. While linters are most definitely helpful, and it is indeed good practice to avoid arbitrary nesting, it's important to understand why a rule is in place and what limitations it imposes. In other words, even when you obey the linter it's desirable understand the rational for the rule. In this case, we must disable the rule because, as we are augmenting an `interface` scoped to a `namespace` and definitions can only be augmented when the augmentation is within the exact same scope - different scopes never colllide.

Basically, the lint rule that you were following inherently precludes your ability to accomplish a very reasonable and common goal - to augment a declaration provided by a library which uses the `namespace` construct to aggregate types thus not polluting the set of globally declared types.

Comment: I have an `eslint` rule. I need to find an alternative. (I'm not allowed to ignore it).

Comment: The rule is just wrong for this scenario. Disable it for the lines in question, and be done with it. There's no other way. A linter mustn't to be followed blindly even though it's usually helpful. Namespaces are how this is expressed in typescript, via declaration merging, which is an idiomatic and essential typescript feature.